# How can I do this comparison in git?

Tags: git

Imagine this structure ( on master and dev_branch ):

```
a/
  b/
  c/
```

I run a script, and it generates this ( dev_branch ):

```
a/
  b/
  c/
    file1
    ...
    fileN
```

I add everything, and I commit it ( dev_branch ).Now, on master, I rewrote the file generating script, I ran it, and I commited it's results. How can I make sure the generated files from master contain the same content as the generated files from branch? How can I perform this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare two branches with:

```
git diff branch1 branch2
```

Or compare working tree with a branch with:

```
git diff branch
```

Comment: Does git take an exclude parameter? For example I don't want it to show me files matching a pattern.

Comment: You can also specify a path. A thorough description can be found in [the manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) as usual.